# Compare columns and print values which does not match.

Tags: awk

Comparing value in column 4 with columns 5 and 6, print the value not found.

If NA value is present in column 4, both values ( column 5 and 6 ) need to be printed.

**Input file**

```
1218885385520000 3240739773    VA     2 24 2 
1218917539980000 3195339725    VA    29 29 30 
1218894095580000 3241939989    VA     7 14 7 
1218892969380000 3242739701    VA    24 24 2 
1218894023580000 3198938973    VA    NA 4 9 
1218883439612000 3199739137    VA    16 16 18 
1218907932780000 3238539773    VA    NA 22 24
1218914177580000 3196739725    VA    29 29 30
```

**Expected output**

```
1218885385520000 3240739773    VA    24 
1218917539980000 3195339725    VA    30 
1218894095580000 3241939989    VA    14 
1218892969380000 3242739701    VA     2 
1218894023580000 3198938973    VA     4
1218894023580000 3198938973    VA     9 
1218883439612000 3199739137    VA    18 
1218907932780000 3238539773    VA    22
1218907932780000 3238539773    VA    24
1218914177580000 3196739725    VA    30
```

I tried

```
awk '$4!=$5 $6 {print $4,"=",$5, $6}' FILE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, not clear please explain it more here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NA never appears in field 5 or field 6 all you need is:

```
$ awk '{for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) if ($4!=$i) print $1, $2, $3, $i}' file
1218885385520000 3240739773 VA 24
1218917539980000 3195339725 VA 30
1218894095580000 3241939989 VA 14
1218892969380000 3242739701 VA 2
1218894023580000 3198938973 VA 4
1218894023580000 3198938973 VA 9
1218883439612000 3199739137 VA 18
1218907932780000 3238539773 VA 22
1218907932780000 3238539773 VA 24
1218914177580000 3196739725 VA 30
```

if `NA` could appear in field 5 or field 6 then you'd just need to tweak the `if` to include that case, i.e. `if ( ($4=="NA") || ($4!=$i) )`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$4=="NA"{print $1,$2,$3,$5 ORS $1,$2,$3,$6;next} {val=$4>$5?$4:$5;print $1,$2,$3,(val>$6?val:$6);val=""}'  Input_file
```